# after() method not working in loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time
root= Tk()
root.title("THis is our other lessons")
root.geometry("600x400")
prog=Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode='determinate')
def bar():
    for i in range(1,100,1):
        prog['value']=i
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.after(2000,root.destroy)
prog.pack()
butt=Button(text="Start",command= bar())
butt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried this method to run the progress bar but it did not worked with `time.sleep`, so I tried `after` method but the output directly reaches to end.

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work"? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead.

Comment: To be clear, you want to destroy your root window 100 times after 100 different 2sec delays? Am I reading that right? Are you worried your root window is a zombie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
butt=Button(text="Start",command= bar())
```

The problem is that you call `bar()` and take the return value as the button's `command`. This causes `bar` to execute immediately instead of when the user clicks the button. To fix this, remove the parentheses to make `bar` itself the command:

```
butt=Button(text="Start",command= bar)
```